# Trello Windows 8 app not updating

Tags: windows-8, trello

Does anybody else have problems with the Windows 8 app of Trello?  Mine doesn't update the boards anymore. It looks like it's infinitely trying to update itself, but nothing happens.

Comment: I would contact the author of Trello for assistance.  I can tell you that knowing the author of Trello the problem is likely something on your end so check the typical causes.

Comment: I did, but while I wait for the answer I thought of posting it here...

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was migrated to SuperUser. Even Trello's website (https://trello.com/help) says "Ask a question on webapps.stackexchange.com, a community-driven Q&A site. Tag your question with trello."

Comment: I would agree that because Trello is a Web Application it shouldn't have moved.  I can only guess that your lack of details made it difficult to determine that.  I still say that you should contact the developer's support staff for assistance with this technical question.

Comment: @Dante your question deals with Trello's Windows 8 app than the webapp, hence I migrated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem just logout and login again.
For logging out, go the the Settings charm while having Trello open.